# Unable to restore models in tensorflow v0.8

Tags: tensorflow, restore

I am trying to restore a saved model . But it is returning me an error. Please help me out. 
**code to save the model : save_model.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
v1 = tf.Variable(1.32, name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(1.33, name="v2")

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "model.ckpt")
```

**code to restore model : restore_model.py**

```
import tensorflow as tf
v1 = tf.Variable(0, name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(0, name="v2")


saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
  print("Model restored.")
```

I have saved both the files in the same directory.

Comment: Please provide the error you're receiving.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. After changing initial values to 0.0 in restore.py, it works properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the error is raised because in `save_model.py` you declare the variables as having type `tf.float32` (the implicit type of `1.32` and `1.33`), whereas in `restore_model.py` you define the variables as having type `tf.int32` (the implicit type of `0`).

The easiest solution would be to modify `restore_model.py` to declare the variables as `tf.float32`. For example, you could do the following:

```
v1 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="v2")
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot ! it works now. I changed the values to 0.0 and it works fine. But after restoring the values of the variables are still 0.0 instead of 1.32 and 1.33. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the full updated source to `restore_model.py` in the question? The variables should never be assigned to 0.0 (unless there's some additional code that runs the initializer for them).

Comment: Hi, the updated code.                                                                                import tensorflow as tf
v1 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="v1")
v2 = tf.Variable(0.0, name="v2")
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  save_path="model.ckpt"
  saver.restore(sess, save_path)
  #print v1.eval(sess)
  print("Model restored.") 
  print v1.eval()