# Use fine-tuned Inception-v3 model to predict on a single image

Tags: python, tensorflow

Even though there are plenty of questions here on SO raising the issue of reusing trained tensorflow models it is still a challenge to use one of the most mainstream model [Inception-v3](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) fine-tuned on a custom dataset to just predict probabilities for some single image.

After having done some research on this topic (the most similar SO-thread is sured to be [Tensorflow: restoring a graph and model then running evaluation on a single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649060/tensorflow-restoring-a-graph-and-model-then-running-evaluation-on-a-single-imag)) I can conclude that having frozen graph.pb file of some trained model is like having a holy grail because you don't need to rebuild graph, choose tensors to restore or whatever — you just call `tf.import_graph_def` and take the output layer you need via `sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name`.

But the problem is that in the examples provided with tensorflow (e.g. classify_image.py), such «frozen graph»'s have nicely prepared input and output points like `DecodeJpeg/contents:0` and `softmax:0` respectively where you can feed your custom images and retrieve the answers from, while you don't have such nice entry points when working with custom fine-tuned model.

For example, fine-tuned Inception-v3 model frozen graph will have `FIFOQueue`, `QueueDequeueMany` and similar dozen of tensors before actual convolutional layers to read batches from TFRecord's and the output tensor will look like `tower_0/logits/predictions` with unusable shape containing batch size, so you just don't have appropriate points to feed a new jpeg image in and get predictions out.

Is there any success story covering usage of such batches-fed fine-tuned models with new images? Or maybe some ideas on changing input pack of TFRecord/batch nodes to JPEG one?

P.S. There is also an alternative for running pretrained models such as TF Serving, but building a huge github repo with plenty of dependencies for every other step seems overwhelming to me.

Comment: You need to load a purposefully-built inference graph instead of the training graph. Slim, tf.contrib.learn.Estimator, keras, and other frameworks all allow you to build a nice inference graph.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the Inception-v3 model, but I have found a work around for a similar situation. 
For training, I use a custom multiprocess/multithread setup to load my samples into batches and feed them into a FIFOQueue. Running inference on the frozen graph always hung indefinitely.
Here is my approach:

Creating frozen inference model:

1. Build a completely separate inference graph. Create placeholders `[in1,in2,...]` for your inputs (with shape corresponding to 1 sample) and create your model the same way you do for training. The output(s) of your model will be referred to as `[out1,out2...]` hereafter.
2. Use `tf.train.Saver()` to load your trained model parameters (for this to work, the names in your new model must match those of your training model). Something like:

   ```
   loader = tf.train.Saver()
   graph = tf.get_default_graph()
   input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       loader.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)
   ```
3. Create a frozen graph:

   ```
   frozen_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
       sess,
       input_graph_def,
       output_node_names)
   ```
4. Optimize model:

   ```
   optimized_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
       frozen_graph_def,
       input_node_names,
       output_node_names, tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)
   ```
5. Save model:

   ```
   with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "wb") as f:
       f.write(optimized_graph_def.SerializeToString())
   ```

Performing inference with frozen model:

1. Load model into `graph`

   ```
   with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
       graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
   with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
       tf.import_graph_def(
           graph_def,
           input_map=None,
           return_elements=None,
           name='',
           op_dict=None,
           producer_op_list=None
       )
   ```
2. Access your inputs/outputs:

   ```
   in1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_tensor_names[0])
   in2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name(input_tensor_names[1])
   ...
   out1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_tensor_names[0])
   ...
   ```
3. Run inference:

   ```
   with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
       sess.run([out1], feed_dict={in1: {data}, in2: {data})
   ```

Tip: How to get the input/output node/tensor names:

```
inputs = [in1, in2...]
outputs = [out1, out2...]

output_tensor_names = [n.name for n in outputs]
input_tensor_names = [n.name for n in inputs]

output_node_names = [n[:str(n).find(":")] for n in output_tensor_names]
input_node_names = [n[:str(n).find(":")] for n in input_tensor_names]
```

I hope this helps.