# Error while testing single image on Cifar 10 tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling

I tried testing a single image on the tensorflow CIFAR 10 tutorial using the code given by bigdata2 for training in the link. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649060/tensorflow-restoring-a-graph-and-model-then-running-evaluation-on-a-single-imag/45004111#45004111?newreg=2b8224786c4e43e3964a675ceb67a06f)
The following changes were made to CIFAR10_train.py

```
def train():   
"""Train CIFAR-10 for a number of steps."""   
  with tf.Graph().as_default():
    global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()

  is_training = tf.placeholder(dtype=bool,shape=(),name='is_training')
  imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (1, 32, 32, 3), name='imgs')
  images = tf.cond(is_training, lambda:images, lambda:imgs)
  logits = cifar10.inference(images)
```

The other change which has been made is

```
 import numpy as np
 tmp_img = np.ndarray(shape=(1,32,32,3), dtype=float)
 with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(
      checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.train_dir,
      hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=FLAGS.max_steps),
        tf.train.NanTensorHook(loss),
        _LoggerHook()],
      config=tf.ConfigProto(
     log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)) as mon_sess:
  while not mon_sess.should_stop():
     mon_sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={is_training: True, imgs: tmp_img})
```

I'm getting the error:

runfile('C:/Users/User/new_train.py', wdir='C:/Users/User')
Filling queue with 20000 CIFAR images before starting to train. This will take a few minutes.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/User/new_train.py', wdir='C:/Users/User')

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/User/new_train.py", line 135, in 
    tf.app.run()

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

File "C:/Users/User/new_train.py", line 131, in main
    train()

File "C:/Users/User/new_train.py", line 77, in train
    logits = cifar10.inference(images)

File "C:\Users\User\cifar10.py", line 246, in inference
    stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)

File "C:\Users\User\cifar10.py", line 135, in _variable_with_weight_decay
    tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev, dtype=dtype))

File "C:\Users\User\cifar10.py", line 111, in _variable_on_cpu
    var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=initializer, dtype=dtype)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1203, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 1092, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 425, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 394, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_windows\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 763, in _get_single_variable
    "but instead was %s." % (name, shape))

ValueError: Shape of a new variable (local3/weights) must be fully defined, but instead was (?, 384).

Can someone give suggestions for rectifying this error?

Comment: Please post some code to reproduce the issue. How are you feeding images to your model?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code(i.e. changes in the Cifar 10 tutorial code in tensorflow website)